# create new object? or reuse existing one?

Tags: javascript, object, dojo

What is a good practice or "correct" practice in JavaScript when you need to wipe out data and put new data?

I use Dojo's Memory and dGrid to display my data. the data gets retrieved every time user clicks 'refresh' button.

the refresh button won't be called many times during the lifetime of the application. 
I have the following code for the grid

```
data = {some JSON data};
store = new Memory({data: data});

grid = new OnDemandGrid({
    selectionMode: 'single',
    store: store
});
```

and the code above is currently run in the method that initialises the application.

and I have another method called '`showGrid`' which will decide the layout of the grid.

then the store is updated when the application receives message with new data.

My concern is, Memory does not have a method for wiping out its data. so I have to loop through the store and put push new data. Perhaps if I don't reuse the store and just create new one, it would be easier or faster.

Then why wouldn't I just create store in the '`showGrid`' method and let it creates store every time user clicks refresh? Speed or memory is not a big concern in the application since data is not that big.

But I want to achieve this in terms of "the correct way" because I learnt creating new objects when it is reusable is important back in my uni days (although it was Java Class not JavaScript).

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Also I would like to know if there's any better way to wipe out Dojo/Object Store/Memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, to answer the questions as directly as possible:

It really isn't up to Dojo to free up memory; that's up to the JavaScript that Dojo is built upon.

To free up the memory in JavaScript, you simply remove any references to the data, and JavaScript will clear the trash out on its own...so the right way to free up the object you have made is simply:

```
grid = null;
```

This should clear this reference and any other references to the same data.

As for 'good practice' for wiping and rewriting data... I am generally agnostic.

You could delete the old one, and create a new one... or simply overwrite this one... even in a relatively large application, I don't believe you would see much of a performance hit or gain either way.

The exception would be if you have a large enough data grid to take up a large chunk of memory, and tried to create a new one before deleting the old one.  But that is a stretch.

In this case, ugly optimizations would fail to improve performance to any real degree, and would cost you in development and troubleshooting time and effort.

To be honest, I generally go for the most readable solution first, and then optimize (only if necessary), down the road.

Often I find that simplifying and clearing up code magically clears away performance bottlenecks, all on its own.

Comment: I am sorry I have missed some code in my question, The Memory stores some data at the time of its creation. But I think you kinda answered to it. I just tested store.data = null and it seems to work. although I think it's a bit hard coding.

Comment: Keep in mind that JavaScript handles most things as REFERENCES... so if you have made numerous references to 'grid', then all the other references are to the exact same space in memory.  Clearing that space in memory clears them all.

Comment: You're right. But since there's no observation from grid side that the data in the store has been set null, the grid does not trigger .update() method to empty the grid display. I was thinking there should be something that does the job in Dojo/store. Anyways thanks for your answer! :)

Comment: Gotcha.  Its slightly hackish, but you could simply create a small function to delete the data, and then trigger the event handler.  You could even attach this directly to grid itself through prototyping, so you could pretty much act as if it was a function native to grid...  grid.clear(), for example.

Comment: Yeah, I'm still noob to JavaScript and gets surprised how flexible the language is. I often looked down on JavaScript thinking it is nothing more than script language for fancy web design and stuff when I used Java. Now I develop node.js and found JS pretty awesome.

Comment: @Eugene Its also one of the fastest evolving language out there... they are supposed to come out with the new Harmony specification sometime soon, as well... not to mention all the features that have recently been added to HTML and CSS... and all the languages that compile directly into JavaScript, like CoffeeScript... can be a lot to absorb.